# What steps do I take to resolve wifi slowness on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop?

Tags: wireless, router

I currently see very bad speeds on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop:

[image: speedof.me slowness]

However, comparing that to the speed test directly on my router, you can see that high speed is coming into my router:

[image: wifi router speedtest]

**Mac Mini**

Connected to the same same wifi router I have a mac mini 2014 which sees the speeds as:

[image: mac mini speed]

What steps should I take to test where the problem is?

Comment: What router are you using? Do you have QoS enabled or is your Mac Mini hogging all the bandwidth and leaving little for other devices. If you don't have or don't want to use QoS you should be able to go into your router settings and set caps on the amount of bandwidth a given device can use in order to free up bandwidth for other devices.

Comment: For a comparison, you should be using the same test server.

Comment: I will check those settings & keep this in mind.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is a very good point.  I hadn't noticed that test server had changed until after I took snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

**1**. First, check out your wifi connection settings under Settings...Wifi...

(some details obfuscated)

[image: wifi net settings]

a.) I removed the check on Make available to other users.

**2**. Notice that the details shows [Supported Frequencies] 2.4GHz / 5GHz
I want to auto connect to my 5GHz network (for higher speeds).

**3**. Select the Identity tab.
(details obfuscated)

[image: wifi identity tab]

I notice there are two choices in the BSSID drop box.
I'm guessing that one  of these is 2.4GHz & the other is 5.0GHz.

I selected the first one and re-ran the speed test.

Now I see much better numbers:

[image: speedof me after changes]

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your router admin page. Under the Wireless settings you may find the option called **Channel Width**. If it is set to `20 MHz` or `20/40 MHz` change it to just `40 MHz`. It should most likely fix the issue. I did the same to fix my slow network problem.